# ExtJS slider not visible on view

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a view on which I am including few controls. All the controls are visible whereas the slider is not visible at all. I have seen the example [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.slider.Single-cfg-renderSelectors) but its not working. Can someone point out any config that I am missing?

```
Ext.define('KPS.view.LaunchPageMain', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    requires: ['Ext.slider.Single'],
    alias: 'widget.launchpagemain',
    layout: 'fit',
    maximized: true,
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    title: 'KPS',
    modal: true, 
    draggable: false,
    tools: [{
        xtype: 'sliderfield',//slider is also not working.
        width: 200,
        value: 3,
        increment: 1,
        minValue: 1,
        maxValue: 5
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        itemId: 'btnUserType',
        text: 'User Roles',
        menu: {
            xtype: 'menu',
            showSeparator: false,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                columns: 1,
                itemId: 'selectionUserTypes',
                vertical: true,
                items: [{
                    boxLabel: 'User',
                    name: 'userSelection',
                    inputValue: 'U'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Admin',
                    name: 'userSelection',
                    inputValue: 'A'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Super Admin',
                    name: 'userSelection',
                    inputValue: 'S'
                }]
            }]
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        itemId: 'btnLogout',
        text: 'Logout'
    }],
    items: [{
    xtype: 'contentView'
}]
});
```

Comment: Leave it folks it is working. The problem is I am using custom theme. With that theme it is not visible. With the default themes it is just working fine. I should have checked that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Since this problem also happened with me, I'll add some details.

In a brand new ExtJS 4 app with a slider, the slider does not show (it is not visible). It will only appear after building the application (`sencha app build`). It is related to the CSS.

After building of the application, `bootstrap.css` changes the source of the CSS, and afterwards, the slider is rendered correctely.

Before the first build (`bootstrap.css`):
`@import 'ext/packages/ext-theme-classic/build/resources/ext-theme-classic-all.css';`

After the first build (`bootstrap.css`):
`@import 'build/production/Slider/resources/Slider-all.css';`

The solution is to build the application.

Comment: your sencha app build tip fixed my issue!  Thanks.